# Размер обводки (CSS)

Tags: css3

Моё почтение!
Начал изучать CSS и HTML, пробую верстать из PSD, столкнулся с такой проблемой, сделал рамку, но на макете она не такого размера (в высоту), кого не затруднит, подскажите как сделать обводку выше и сделать отступ между текстом и собственно обводкой. Ниже прикрепил код:

```
#counter{
  font-size: 16px;
  position: relative;
  left: -4%;
  color: #fff;
  top: 75px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: inline;
  height: 100px;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Заранее благодарен за любую помощь

Comment: Не очень понятно, но ощущение, что display: inline-block (вместе inline) и padding - то что нужно

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/uHApFaM.png

Указал padding 1% получилась такая штука :D

Comment: не очень понятно что требуется ... проще наверное даже было бы, если скинул пнгшку того что должно получиться и кто-то (ну например я) сверстал бы, а дальше бы уже сидел, сам ковырялся какие параметры и для чего в верстке

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/HNau0

Таки допёр, спасибо большое!

  padding-top: 9px;
  padding-right: 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 9px;

Comment: padding: 9px 2px; Не за что